# Could not open input file: C\Program

Tags: php, localhost, command-prompt

I am using two drives
One(HDD) that came pre-installed with my laptop
Second(M.2 SSD) that I installed later
I made the second drive as primary boot drive

Both C(HDD) and H(SSD) has the Windows operating system because I copied it to SSD(H) with Samsung magician software and didn't delete the OS in C drive.

but as i said earlier, the system boots from H because i made it primary boot drive.

I downloaded the php zip and unzipped it in a folder called php inside H drive (H:\php)

Now how can I set environment for this?
I tried setting environment variable but when I execute php %PATH% in command prompt it says "Could not open input file:C\Program"

Also when i tried to create localhost:4000 to run php but nothing happens on browser

This picture might help you

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq3SZ.jpg)

Please help

Comment: Seems like you have to update your `PATH` with your new os(change `C:\Program Files` to `H:\Program files` etc)

Comment: Can you be precise where exactly it needs to be done

Comment: In the Program `change Environment variables`